# JAXB serializing array with wrong name

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2

I have an xsd schema definition like this (definition was provided to me and is used by a wsdl so I am trying to avoid changing the schema):

```
...
<xs:complexType name="PricingServicesGroupOwner">
    <xs:sequence>
        ...
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="servicePreferences" nillable="true"
                    type="tns:ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner"/>
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ServicePreferenceOwner" nillable="true"
                    type="tns:ServicePreferenceOwner"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner"/>
...
```

The problem is in the inner element of type "ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner" which is supposed to be named "servicePreferences" so I expect to see that name in the serialized xml element, but when the object gets serialized I get this:

```
...
    <ns3:PricingServicesGroupOwner>
        ...
        <ns3:ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner>
            <ns4:ServicePreferenceOwner>
            ...
        </ns3:ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner>
            ...
    </ns3:PricingServicesGroupOwner>
...
```

What is expected is something like this:

```
...
    <ns3:PricingServicesGroupOwner>
        ...
        <ns3:servicePreferences>
            <ns4:ServicePreferenceOwner>
            ...
        </ns3:servicePreferences>
            ...
    </ns3:PricingServicesGroupOwner>
...
```

The JAXB class has this name definition with annotations:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner", namespace = "http://myschema...", ...
public class ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner {
```

What I tried:

1. Changing the name attribute in the annotation:

   ```
   @XmlType(name ="servicePreferences",...
   ```
2. Using jaxb bindings:

   ```
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="serviceSchema.xsd">
       <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner']">
           <jaxb:property name="servicePreferences"/>
       </jaxb:bindings>
       <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner']">
           <jaxb:property name="servicePreferences"/>
       </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
   ```

None of these have effect.

Comment: Maybe show a more complete schema, including the definition of the element:  <ns3:PricingServicesGroupOwner> (you just showed the type def), and also <schema> level attributes like elementFormDefault.

Answer (score 0):

In PricingServicesGroupOwner class, use @XmlElement(name = "servicePreferences") for element ArrayOfServicePreferenceOwner.